# Search-Plugin for Eclipse

Tags: search, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, search-engine, mask

i have written am Eclipse-plugin and now need to extend it with a search functionality. I know that Eclipse has a search feature, but it does only search the workspace and what i need is to look after matches within my own plugin and than to show the result in a tree structure. Is there any examples of search-plugins for Eclipse? I would appreciate a link of some hint :D

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [org.eclipse.search.searchPages](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/search_page.htm) extension.