# Can we use eclipse C/C++ and File search plugin APIs in our plugin (meant for eclipse only)?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, full-text-search, eclipse-cdt, file-search

Referring to my previous question : [Search-Plugin for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10219441/search-plugin-for-eclipse)

Now I am able to use eclipse JDT Search API in my plugin. But I am able to search in Java files only. Now I want to embed C/C++ and File search functionality to search in non-java files also like C, C++, XML etc files. If we directly can't do that then suggest some alternative. I have gone through lots of queries on stackoverflow and other websites but could not find any fruitful content.

Comment: Your question is not clear enough. Do you want to use CDT (https://eclipse.org/cdt/)?

Comment: Yes I want to use CDT. I have searched a lot. But I am not able to find any API for CDT search plugin. @AryeShemesh

Comment: Maybe this can help: https://wiki.eclipse.org/images/c/c7/CDT_APIs_for_code_introspection.pdf

Comment: I have checked this pdf but didnt get required info...
Actually I am implementing a plugin for java and c/c++ files and wanted to use search functionality (ctrl + h) to search references of function in java, c and c++ file. I have used JDT search api org.eclipse.jdt.core.search.

In same manner I am searching similar api which I can use to search functions references in C / C++ files of a project.